# Finding singularities and residues

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve this question.

$$\frac{(\pi- z)(z^4 -3z^2)}{\sin^{2}z}$$

The above is the given function and I am suppose to find the singular points and their corresponding residues.

My approach was as follows.

$\sin^2z = 0$ means $z = n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

But $z = 0$ is a removable singularity as,
$$\frac{(\pi- z)(z^2 -3)}{\frac{\sin^{2}z}{z^2}} $$
the value of $$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin^2z}{z^2} = 1$$

But I am not sure wheather other singularities are essential or non-removable and how to go about finding their residues.

Please give me hint on how to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=w+n\pi$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\sin^2(z)=\sin^2(w+n\pi)=((-1)^n\sin(w))^2=\sin^2(w)$. Therefore
$$f(z):=\frac{(\pi- z)(z^4 -3z^2)}{\sin^{2}z}=\frac{(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3)}{\sin^{2}w}\\=\frac{(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3)}{w^2(1+O(w^2))}\\
=\frac{(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3)}{w^2}\cdot (1-O(w^2)).$$
because
$\sin(w)=w-\frac{w^3}{6}+ O(w^5)$ implies that $$\sin^2(w)=w^2-2w\cdot\frac{w^3}{6}+ O(w^6)=w^2-\frac{w^4}{3}+ O(w^6)=w^2+O(w^4).$$

Now we are you able to classify the singularities $\{n\pi\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of $f$.

Note that for $n\not=0,1$, the numerator is different from zero at $w=0$. Therefore in that case the order of $n\pi$ is TWO. The residue is the coefficient of $1/w$ of 
$$
\frac{(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3)}{w^2}\cdot (1-O(w^2))$$
that is the coefficient of $w$ of the numerator
$$(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3).$$
Therefore
$$\mbox{Res}(f;n\pi)=3n(3n-2)\pi^2-(5n-4)n^3\pi^4.$$

For $n=0$ then
$$f(z)=\frac{(\pi-w)w^2(w -3)}{w^2(1+O(w^2))}=\frac{(\pi-w)(w -3)}{1+O(w^2)}$$
which implies that $z=0$ is a removable singularity and $\mbox{Res}(f;0)=0$.

For $n=1$ then
$$f(z)=\frac{w(w+\pi)^2((w+\pi)^2 -3)}{w^2(1+O(w^2))}=\frac{(w+\pi)^2((w+\pi)^2 -3)}{w(1+O(w^2))}$$
which implies that $z=\pi$ has order ONE and
$$\mbox{Res}(f;\pi)=[(w+\pi)^2((w+\pi)^2 -3)]_{w=0}=\pi^4-3\pi^2.$$

Comment: Thanks Robert for your quick response.Can you please elaborate a bit.what does $w^2(1+o(w))$ mean.

Comment: It means that the series expansion of $\sin^2(w)=w^2+a_1w^4+\dots$.

Comment: Not able to proceed further. Further help required

Comment: Do you know what the Taylor expansion of an analytic function is?

Comment: I understood the series and stuff..but how do I proceed with classifying the singularities.

Comment: Should I find the coefficient of $1/z$ for residue

Comment: @ANUPAM BISHT You should find the coe4fficent of $1/w$ of $\frac{(\pi- (w+n\pi))(w+n\pi)^2((w+n\pi)^2 -3)}{w^2}$. See my edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45239/discussion-between-anupam-bisht-and-robert-z).

Comment: Won't the function change completely if I write z = w + n pi

Comment: @ANUPAM BISHT No, it's just a translation, if $z\to n\pi$ is equivalent to $w\to 0$.

Comment: I am sorry.Unintentional